# google chrome developer tools mobile emulator only shows small portion of screen

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, emulation

In the developer tools of chrome the mobile emulator shows only a fraction of the webpage in the top left corner but the rest of the page is blank.

Comment: What is the tech stack of the web page.  Is it mobile-first, HTML5, server-side?

Comment: Probably https://crbug.com/819489

Answer (score 0):

One work around is if you select the mobile option dropdown on the center of the mobile emulated page you can select edit and enter your desired dimensions. When you choose the newly created option the screen looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen by box in red in image, you can adjust the resolution in the top of the menu.

[image]

Comment: How do I "just turn off" the "dimensions responseive" thing"?  Chrome was scaled just fine until I launched the devtools.  That's set to open in a separate window so there's no logical reason for the window to be resized.


What I'd like to be able to do is examine the DOM, but actually see fields on screen as well, and not have them too small to read.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue it only shows the top left corner. That's for all webpages on mac version of chrome. I fixed the issue by going back to an older version.

[Privew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAYs8.png)